# AngularJS Get Property Inside Array from Inside Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have an object called $rootScope.data

```

```
$rootScope.data = {
        model: 'build',
        availableOptions: [
            { logo: 'https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/balanced-
                e28093c2a0logo.png', 
              name: 'Balanced' 
            }
        ]
    }
```

```

I display it in the view with :

```

```
<select id="category" ng-model="data.model">
    <option ng-repeat="data in data.availableOptions" value="{{data.logo}}">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

```

and the push function is:

```

```
$scope.addGateway = () => {
        console.log($scope.data.model)
        $scope.gateways.push({
            logo: $scope.data.model,
            status: 'ENABLED',
            statusColor: 'green-darken-1'
        })
    }
```

```

Then I have a button that pushes into a new array, it does what I want it to do: to push the logo of a company. But I don't know how I can access or push the `name` inside the `availableOptions` to the new array.

I'm using AngularUI Bootstrap by the way so the push function is in another controller.

Comment: from where are you getting `name` ?

Answer (score 0):

I might just be hungry. Haha. After I ate, I went in and coded again and I was so dumb I haven't gotten it the first time:

```
const checkForSame = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < gateways.length; i++) {
        $scope.test = gateways[i].name
        if ($scope.data.model == $scope.test) {
            console.log('same!')
            return
        }
        else {
            console.log('not same!')
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```